# Determining position with respect to time

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

If we assume $s(t)$ as a time-dependent position function and $v(t)$ as a time-dependent velocity function($v = \frac {\mathrm{d}s} {\mathrm{d}t}$) and $v=8\sqrt{s}$, how could I determine $s$ with respect to $t$?

Answer (score 3):

You're written the majority of it yourself, you have $$8\sqrt{s} = \frac{\mathrm{d}s}{\mathrm{d}t}.$$

Separating the variables gives $$\int 8 \, \mathrm{d}t  = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{s}} \, \mathrm{d}s$$

So $$8t = 2\sqrt{s} + c \iff \sqrt{s} = \frac{8t - c}{2}$$

Where $c$ is some additive constant. To determine the constant. You know that at time $t=0$, you've moved a distance  of $0$. So $t=s=0$. Replacing those into the above equation yields $$0 = 2\sqrt{0} + c\iff c= 0.$$

So you get $$\sqrt{s} = 4t \implies s = 16t^2.$$

Comment: And then you can put in s=t=0 to find out exact value of c(=0)

Comment: @user3313320, thanks for that! :-)

Comment: Surely, it would be better to write $\sqrt{s} = 4t - c,$ as $c$ is still a constant to be found, and is, therefore, unaffected by the fact that we have divided it by two to remove the fraction.

Comment: @Taylor, that wouldn't be entirely correct. We could write $\sqrt{s} = 4t - d$, for some arbitrary constant $d = \frac{c}{2}$. I chose not to, since I proceeded to find the value of $c$ in a moment anyway.